# Зачем нужен r' ' - литерал в модуле re. И нужен ли?

Tags: python, строковый-литерал, re

В докуметации по модулю [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) есть примеры использования паттернов как в формате обычной строки " ", так и специфической  r" " - строкой:

```
import re
m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
m.group(0)
```

и

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=-)\w+', 'spam-egg')
m.group(0)
```

они чем то отличаются в работе и когда их нужно использовать?

Comment: raw string. Это  не обязательно регулярки, например, можно написать путь в виндах `r'c:\ps\'`, не экранируя слэши дл читаемости

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ содержится в самом верху страницы:

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with `'r'`. So `r"\n"` is a two-character string
>   containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

Коротко: `r`-строки не требуют экранирования спецсимволов (например, `\`, а обычные требуют). `r"\n"` это два символа - `\` и `n`, а `"\n"` - один символ (перевод строки).